# Out of Memory (java heap) when running suite with too many test cases

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, out-of-memory

I have a suite that references multiple test classes.  In total, there are 15,354 test cases.  When I run the suite, I am getting out of memory error at the 11000th mark (more or less).

I am running it on Win 7 64-bit with 4G RAM.  I have also maxed out my java heap in the run configuration of eclipse to 1536M.

It runs fine if I run the test classes individually.  Is there a technique/or guideline I can follow to reduce my memory foot print?

I have previously refactored the code to utilize a super class on my test cases and use class variables to reduce memory consumption, but now it won't cut it anymore.

Comment: are resources freed after each test case?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771104/junit-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-when-running-all-tests-in-a-package

I tried the suggestion to null out the object instance being tested on tearDown(), I can't believe it worked for me.  Please forgive me for asking too soon.  Thank you for all the useful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As ar as I know there is a difference between junit and testng:

- junit is initializing all test cases before running the first one
- testng is initializing the test it will actually start

But I can't find the diagram, which was showing the running time of the same test written in testng compared to junit.

Comment: I agree with you, I did a System.out.println in the constructor before in junit. I don't have experience with TestNG though.

Comment: Me neither, BUT it SHOULD be nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

You have several techniques to adjust memory heap. The simplest option is to use -Xms. You can see [reducing java memory](http://blog.griddynamics.com/2010/01/java-tricks-reducing-memory-consumption.html).